# Oracle shard availability pending

Tags: oracle, sharding

Trying to adjust Oracle DB 12.2 sharding configuration. Have one DB as the shard catalog and other two DBs as shards. Just want to test this functionality so run the tree DBs on the same machine in the same ORACLE_HOME. Using composite sharding method.

All the things done according to the official documentation. `GDSCTL> config` shows  nothing wrong as I can see. But:

```
GDSCTL>config shard
Name                Shard Group         Status    State       Region     Availability
----                -----------         ------    -----       ---------- --------
ape002              shrdgrp_oper        Ok        Replicated  reg_oper   PENDING
ape003              shrdgrp_arch        Ok        Replicated  reg_arch   PENDING
```

In the example in the documentation, the states are "Deployed" and the Availabilities are "ONLINE" and "READ_ONLY". Every time I try to redeploy I get:

```
GDSCTL>deploy
deploy: examining configuration...
deploy: requesting chunk deployment on shards in shardgroup 'shrdgrp_oper'  via GSM ...
deploy: requesting chunk deployment on shards in shardgroup 'shrdgrp_arch' via GSM ...
deploy: shards configured successfully
GSM Warnings:
shrdgrp_oper ape002:ORA-45598: Shard  is in converted state , it should be either "PRIMARY" or "PHYSICAL STANDBY".
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3865
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3827
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3861
ORA-06512: at line 1 (ngsmoci_execute)
shrdgrp_arch ape003:ORA-45598: Shard  is in converted state , it should be either "PRIMARY" or "PHYSICAL STANDBY".
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3865
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3827
ORA-06512: at "GSMADMIN_INTERNAL.DBMS_GSM_DBADMIN", line 3861
ORA-06512: at line 1 (ngsmoci_execute)
```

And in the shard catalog I get:

```
SQL> alter session enable shard ddl;
ERROR:
ORA-02521: attempted to enable shard DDL in a non-shard database
```

Though in the two shards this `alter session` works. Can't find what this "PENDING" availability means, i.e. what it waits for, and what to do to complete the process.

Can anyone help me to get it to work?

Comment: Can you share commands you used to add shards?

Comment: That was the time I tried to test Oracle sharding feature. The installation and configuration process was very complicated and hard, and the official documentation was rather discouraging. After quite a long time of trying in the end I gave it up completely and don't want to even think about this worthless craft again :( So sorry, cannot restore my records of those days. Anyway my hugest good lucks to those courageous guys who will stand up this thorny path!

Answer (score 1):

What To Do If Something Is Not Right

If any shards are showing an availability of PENDING, confirm that all steps related to ADD INVITEDNODE and CONFIG VNCR from the topology configuration were completed. If not, complete them now and run GDSCTL SYNC DATABASE -database shard_name to complete shard deployment.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/shard/sharded-database-deployment1.html#GUID-1DDE95AD-D1B6-4012-9F3E-8833A16E5774

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).